# 3 Vb.net Forms - I Can get the title from one but not the other?

Tags: vb.net, forms, class, title, public

I have 3 forms in my solution file. Each one has a **Public** class in it.

(Form1 - **MainControlWindow** Class), (Form3 - **ShaneTestFormVersion2** Class), (New_Popup_Chords - **New_Popup_Chords** Class)

The program starts off in Form1 in the MainControlWindow Class.  I give it a title name and I dim the second form, ShaneTestFormVersion2 class as frmSongDisplay2 and display it.

```
        Me.Text = "Window_A"
        Dim frmSongDisplay2 As New ShaneTestFormVersion2
        frmSongDisplay2.Show()
```

And then, in the ShaneTestFormVersion2 class on the Form3.vb page, I dim the last form as a dialog so the second forms processing halts while its open:

```
        Me.Text = "Window_B"
        Dim NewChordsPopup As New New_Popup_Chords
        NewChordsPopup.ShowDialog()
```

This all works fine and dandy until I try to use the 3rd form (NewChordsPopup) to display the window titles of the other 2:

```
    MsgBox(ShaneTestFormVersion2.Text) 'Second Form opened
    MsgBox(MainControlWindow.Text) 'First Form Opened
```

The msgsboxes come up as the default window title as *"Form3"* not *"Window_B"*, but the first window msgbox comes up fine as *"Window_A"*.

The titles were all set the same way, the windows were dimed and displayed the same way. Why does ShaneTestFormVersion2 in Form3 come up as *"Form3"* instead of the title I assigned it, *"Window_B"*?

Side Note:

I also notice that I can access MainControlWindow variables (MainControlWindow.Var1) fine (Public Var1) but can't access ShaneTestFormVersion2 varables (ShaneTestFormVersion2.Var1) without it being "Public Shared Var1".

Comment: Your instance is called frmSongDisplay2, not ShaneTestFormVersion2.  So you want frmSongDisplay2.Text.

Comment: It comes up underlined in blue and says frmSongDisplay2 not declared. I'm trying to get the Title of that instance but from another form, do I dim it on that page too?

Comment: You have to pass a reference to it.  That it worked for the first form is a happy accident because Microsoft was trying to be compatible with the old VB6 architecture.

Comment: Can i get some example code on how to do that?

Comment: `Dim frmSongDisplay2 As New ShaneTestFormVersion2(Me)`  Then in the other constructor, add `Public Sub New(mainForm As Form)`

Comment: Ok, i added the "Me" argument on the first page where I dim the instance of TestFomrVersion2. It gave a error saying Me was too many arguments. What constructor to i add that argument too?

Comment: Not the first form, which is presumably your main form.  Try  ShaneTestFormVersion2

Comment: So I just make it a empty sub? or do I add the "mainForm As Form" to an existing sub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a reference.

Add a constructor in your ShaneTestFormVersion2 form:

```
Public Class ShaneTestFormVersion2
  Private mainForm As Form

  Public Sub New(mainForm as Form)
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.mainForm = mainForm
  End Sub
```

Then in your code, it would be:

```
MessageBox.Show(mainForm.Text)
```

or you can use the Owner property:

```
frmSongDisplay2.Show(Me)
```

Then in the ShaneTestFormVersion2 form, you would use:

```
MessageBox.Show(Me.Owner.Text)
```

Comment: It still doesnt see it. So i put your constructor my 3rd form and added the (Me) parameter to the second and it seems to work :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening that In you Main form, you are declaring the new forms as private and as such the other forms won't be able to see each other. Declare the form as Friend and reference it like below

Try changing your declaration ..

```
Dim frmSongDisplay2 As New ShaneTestFormVersion2
```

to ..

```
Friend frmSongDisplay2 As New ShaneTestFormVersion2
```

and ..

```
MsgBox(ShaneTestFormVersion2.Text) 'Second Form opened
```

to ..

```
MsgBox(MaincontrolWindow.frmSongDisplay2.Text) 'Second Form opened
```